# useFieldArray react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

There is something that I am blocking and it makes no sense at all. For you who are familiar with react-hook-form, I am attempting to create a dynamic field array that renders according to the state object. The thing is, it renders on the first render but not on the second render.

Example:

```
    let subK = [{ name: '' }]
    if (kategories[kategori] !== undefined) {
        //subK = kategories[kategori].subKategori.map(x => ({ name: JSON.stringify(x) }))
        subK = kategories[kategori].subKategori.map(x => ({ name: (x) }))
    }
    console.log(subK) // it logs[{name: 'kat1'},{name: 'kat2'}]

    //defines the form
    const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            subKategori: subK
        }
    });
```

**does not render subK**.

But if I do

```
    let subK = [{ name: '' }]
    if (kategories[kategori] !== undefined) {
        //subK = kategories[kategori].subKategori.map(x => ({ name: JSON.stringify(x) }))
        subK = kategories[kategori].subKategori.map(x => ({ name: (x) }))
    }
    console.log(subK)

    //defines the form
    const { register, control, handleSubmit } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            subKategori: [{name: 'kat1'},{name: 'kat2'}]
        }
    });
```

**it renders as it is supposed too.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io) for reproducing the issue?

Comment: @NiyasNazar not really. The project is quite big and for a client. Don't want it to leak over the internet and the code blocks that I provided are the core of react-hook-form and useFieldArray()

Comment: Where does `kategories` come from ?

Comment: @nubinub from the state.

Comment: As suggested by @NiyasNazar, you should really narrow down and abstract the problem you are facing. First of all it might help you solve the problem, and second of all it will allow you to post a sandbox.

Comment: @nubinub  https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-raman-o8djc

Comment: In the sandbox you provided, there is at least one issue, you are trying to call `map`, on a string value. `subkategori` need to be array in order to call `map`.

Comment: can you take a look the offical doc: https://react-hook-form.com/api#useFieldArray? there is an example in there and some of the key notes too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor issue in the structure of `subKategori` at line number 8. It seems an array is in stringified form. But for `map`, you need an array. Converting it as following at line number 8 shall work :

```
....
 kat1: {
          subKategori: ["kat1", "kat2"]
        },
...
```

Here is the updated sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-matsumoto-ry70q?file=/src/App.js)